# Convolution kernels

Tags: machine-learning, python, kernel-trick, convolution

Below are two different convolution kernel formulas, `h` and `H`, written in Python which I think are both symmetric. What is the difference between them application-wise in statistical learning? are they somehow equivalent and both Gaussian-based, and why the normalization at both's end?

#### Kernel 1

```
x = concatenate( (arange(0,n/2), arange(-n/2,0)) );
[Y, X] = meshgrid(x, x)
h = exp((-X**2-Y**2)/ (2*s**2))
h = h/sum(h.flatten())
```

#### Kernel 2

```
self.H = np.zeros(2*w+1);
for i in range(-w,w+1):
    self.H[i+w] = np.exp(-(i*i)/sig**2);
#self.H *= 1.0/(np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)*sig);
self.H /= np.sum(self.H);
```